# Sequelize return object

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and typescript, with await keyword.
When I return object, it returns a sequelize object.

```
createFolder : async (request:Express.Request, response:Express.Response)  =>  {
        const requestedFolderName = request.body.folderName
        const folderCreated =  await sequelize.models['FolderDoc'].create({
            name: requestedFolderName
        })                                      
        return response.status(201).send(folderCreated)                                 
    }
```

I want to return a json object. How can I do that ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `toJSON` :

```
return response.status(201).send(folderCreated.toJSON())
```

**OR**

It will return data only if it's Postgres

```
// returning : true , (returns data)
// raw : true (returns plain data | will ignore field and virtual setters)

const folderCreated =  await sequelize.models['FolderDoc'].create({
    name: requestedFolderName
},{
    returning : true ,
    raw : true
});
```

Comment: Just a **note** if you ever user `findAll` or a method that returns an array, `toJSON()` is not available to you

Answer (score 0):

I normally use

```
res.status(201).json({
            message: "message_string",
            data: folderCreated
        });
```